# How can I get MediaWiki and WordPress to share login credentials in an intranet?

Tags: wordpress, mediawiki, login, passwords

We have several products that our staff are required to login to in order to use.

Is there a way to get MediaWiki and WordPress to utilize the same login information without manually setting each product to the same username and password combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution here - **[AuthWordpress](http://mikehummel.de/wiki/index.php?title=Tool:AuthWordpress)**:

- [Sharing WordPress session cookie with MediaWiki (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309528/sharing-wordpress-session-cookie-with-mediawiki)